# Sending data formData througt Javascript to Express API

Tags: javascript, express

So, when i handle a post request througt javascript, i send the data to the api, and i don't know how to log the data in the API.

**What i tried**

```
app.post("/register", (req,res) => {
    res.render("register/register", {});
    -> i tried to log it as req.query, req.params or req.body console.log(req.query)
})
```

**JS code:**

```
document.querySelector("#regForm").addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = document.querySelector("#username").value;

    let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#regForm"));
    
    console.log([...formData]);

    let data = JSON.stringify([...formData]);
    console.log(data)
        
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", '/register');
        request.send(data);
    })
```

Edit:
**The full API code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
const port = process.env.POST || "8080";

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
})
// middleware & static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));
app.get("/profile/:name", (req,res) => {
    res.render("profile", {username:req.params.name});
})

app.get("/register", (req,res) => {
    res.render("register/register", {});
})

app.post("/register", jsonParser, (req,res) => {
    res.render("register/register", {});
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

**Answer to LakiMancic - The error:**
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTlLL.png)

And nothing works. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Im going to put the api's code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify Content-Type of your XMLHttpRequest with

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

After request.open(...); and before request.send(...);

**Update ( Full Code that worked for me )**:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/main.html');
});

app.post("/register", (req,res) => { 
    console.log(req.body)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

```js
document.querySelector("#regForm").addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let username = document.querySelector("#username").value;

            let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#regForm"));
            
            console.log([...formData]);

            let data = JSON.stringify([...formData]);
            console.log(data)
            
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("POST", '/register');
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            request.send(data);
        })
```

Comment: It gives me an error. I'll put the error in the question

Comment: Maybe you don't need jsonParser in app.post('/register', ...), try without it

Comment: Then it gives me an empty value ( {} )

Comment: I updated answer, I added code that worked for me, try to use it to fix your code